# Proving trig relations in a circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

From the Picture 
Following identities are true for every cirlce
$$ If\space 2\varphi+\theta=180$$
$$\frac{1}{\cos\theta}-1=\frac{tan\theta}{\tan\varphi}\space -Eqn\space 1$$
$$\frac{1}{2cos^2\varphi}-1=\frac{tan\varphi}{tan\theta}\space-Eqn\space 2$$
Any Proof for this identities ?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you express all those trigonometrics as proportions of side lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the top vertex of the triangle be $D$. $$\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi}}$$ $$\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}.\frac{\cos\varphi}{\sin\varphi}$$ $$1-\cos\theta=\sin\theta\cos\varphi\csc\varphi$$
$$1-\frac{AB}{AD}=\frac{BD}{AD}.\frac{BC}{CD}.\frac{DC}{DB}$$
$$AD=AC$$ $$BC=BD.\frac{BC}{DB}$$ 
$$BC=BC$$ $$\text{Q.E.D.}$$
For (ii),
$$\frac{1}{cos^2\varphi\cdot2}-1=\frac{tan\varphi}{tan\theta}$$ 
$$\frac{-\cos2\varphi}{2\cos^2\varphi}=\frac{\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi}*\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
$$\frac{-\cos2\varphi}{\sin2\varphi}=\cot\theta$$
So we have to prove that $$-\cot2\varphi=\cot\theta$$
Now use: $\cot2\varphi=\frac12[\cot\varphi-\tan\varphi]$

 I think you can take it from here.

Comment: That is 2(cosine function)

Comment: You can still improve your question.

Comment: since $$2\varphi+\theta=180$$ $$-\cot(180-\theta)=cot\theta$$ $$cot(180-a)=-cot(a)$$ then $$cot\theta=cot\theta$$

Comment: What about [on hold] what is wrong with is qustion?

Comment: Well done! (y)..

Comment: You didn't show your own work, your confusions. This site, as said before, is not for homework or the Q&A style. It clears your confusions. SO you have to add your own work also.

Comment: Read the help page for more info.

Comment: thank you for your answers